# Remove the first number surrounded by space

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that looks like

```
2 3 5 5 5
```

I need to remove the second number out of this string, what's the easiest way to do it?
Output should be:

```
2 5 5 5
```

More examples:
Input:

```
1 4 23 44 52 62
```

Output:

```
1 23 44 52 62
```

Input:

```
5 2 3 4
```

Output:

```
5 3 4
```

**Edit:**
I know I can call .split(" ") and get an array and then join the rest, but I am looking for a more elegant solution, such as a regular expression that can avoid a loop

Comment: I thought about that, but then I would get an array of int, so thought there might be an easier way to do it

Comment: Why would it be an array of int's? Its a string, split gives you an array of strings, then join gives you back a string.

Comment: string, that's what I meant

Comment: You just join the array again so you end up with one string at the end.

Comment: But you need a loop to loop through the array except the second string right? I think there is gonna be a way I don't have to loop it through

Comment: You don't need a loop. See my answer (its in C# but you should be able to get an idea of how its done).

Comment: Looking at the answers below, I think using `split` is more concise and readable than a regular expression. Neither approach requires a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `string.replaceFirst`

```
string.replaceFirst("(?m)^(\\d+)\\s+\\d+", "$1");
```

**OR**

```
string.replaceFirst("\\s+\\d+", "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xG9mD7/1)

Comment: That's just beautiful

Answer (score 0):

Something along this line would work:

```
String str = "2 3 5 5 5";

int first = str.indexOf(" ");
int second = str.indexOf(" ", first +1);

if (second > -1)
  return str.subString(0, first) + str.subString(second);
```

Comment: I didn't test this, so you may need a -1 or +1 when getting the substrings if you don't end up with the correct space layout in the output.  Though the core idea should be functional.

Comment: No, I did the math and the spacing should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly familiar with Java's string utilities, but if possible you could loop through each character in the string, and record the positions if the first two space characters (x and y). Then you could take a substring starting at 0 and x characters long, then concatenate it with a substring starting at y and going to the end of the string.

I am on my phone right now, and Google keyboard isn't exactly code-friendly, so sorry that I can't give you a full implementation.

Comment: I am trying to avoid a loop of any sort

Comment: Why? A simple for loop will not give you any trouble, and there's always the index of function that the other answer uses.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough context to state what the most elegant solution would be, but since you don't quite want to use split, another options is using regular expressions:

```
Matcher m = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(\\d[ ]*)(\\d)[ ]*(.*)").
        matcher("5 2 3 4");
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + m.group(3));
}
```

Output in this case would be:

```
5 3 4
```

What I think is nice about using regular expressions is that you can easily adapt them if the setting is slightly different. For example, if instead of all numbers you get an arbitrary string of characters at the beginning or something like that.

Getting used to regular expressions can take a bit of time, but there is plenty of documentation online or, of course, you could post another question over here :).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
String s = "1 4 23 44 52 62".replaceFirst("(\\s[0-9]+\\s)", " ");
```

Comment: It is better to use + than *. In this case might be same result but can be an issue if there are 2 spaces together

Answer (score 0):

This is C# syntax but you should be able to translate it pretty easily.

```
public string RemoveSecondNumber(string s)
{
    string[] split = s.Split(' ');
    List<string> output = split.ToList();

    output.RemoveAt(1);

    return String.Join(" ", output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can **split** that **string** using **space parameter** into an **array** then remove the second **array index** then put the rest of the array parts together again with the space like this :

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("2 3 5 5 5", " ");
```

print the array output to see the results

```
while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println("StringTokenizer Output: " + st.nextElement());
    }
```

for more details check [This Link](http://crunchify.com/java-stringtokenizer-and-string-split-example/)

i hope you got my point

Comment: Important :  Put in mind if your string has a double space or more for example   "2---3-5----5------5"  instead of  "2-3-5-5-5" note that (-) mean a space that is way  you need to loop your array after split and romove any array value that is space or empty then do the rest